# Run php script using GET method and query a database for results

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I apologise for asking a very similar question to others, but I can't quite get my head around this. Bascially, I need to show a html page which I already have set up with a form that gets information from a PHP script. So far, in the HTML, I have

```
<!-- FORM START -->
    <form action="checkscript.php" method="get">
        <!-- Input text box with styling over image -->
        <input type="text" style="position:relative; left:8px; top:-75px; font-family:arial; font-size:32px; background-color:transparent; height:44px; width:268px; border:none; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center;" placeholder="TICKET ID" maxlength="7" name="ticketId" />
        <!-- Button with styling to execute PHP script -->
        <button type="button" style="position:relative; top:-45px; width:300px; height:30px; font-family:arial; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">Find Details</button> 
    </form>
```

And in the checkscript.php which queries the database, I have

```
<?php
$db = mssql_connect("dbsrv02", "requsr", "");
mssql_select_db("ticketDb",$db);
$result = mssql_query("SELECT ticketId, StageOne, StageTwo, StageThree",$db);
$num = mssql_num_rows($result);
$regPlate = $_GET['ticketId'];
$i = 1;
if ($myrow = mssql_fetch_array($result)) do {
    <<< what goes here? >>>
}
if ($num > $i) printf(",");
$i++;
} while ($myrow = mssql_fetch_array($result));
else {
echo "Sorry, nothing there to see!";
}
?>
```

And now, what I need is to know what to put in where it says <<< what goes here? >>>. I need to use something like

```
if ($myrow["StageOne"] = "Completed" and $myrow["StageTwo"] = "Uncomplete" and $myrow["StageThree"] = "Uncomplete" {
    $stage = "StageOne"
}
```

(the word either Completed or Uncomplete will be in the row under the column "StageOne", "StageTwo" and "StageThree").

to find the results in the same row as the 'ticketId', and how to show the information retrieved as HTML e.g. if the $stage variable = "StageOne", specific elements are shown in the HTML.

Sorry, I know it must be quite simple but I could do with some help here. Any help would be appreciated, especially if you can make it really detailed!

Thanks

Ed

Comment: `if..do` seriously? Did you mean `do..while` method?

Comment: @Mr. Smith Not sure. Can you explain please? I don't know that much about that. I just know If commands because of other languages!

Comment: `if() do {}` is not [correct syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).

Comment: You might want to have a look at how if is used in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: @Mr.Smith Oh ok, sorry. Do you think you'd be able to correct the code, or even better, help me fill in the blanks? And thanks for the link @codejak!

Comment: @EdG you've accidentally posted your complete credential to access your database. You should change them as soon as possible!

Comment: @Angelo Thanks for taking a look at it - but that isn't the password, that is just a load of letters I put in place of it! But thanks for letting me know just in case!

Comment: @EdG Oh ok :) sorry for the edit

Comment: It's no problem, I'm glad someone was worried about it though and didn't try and just take it!

Answer (score 0):

Try code below :

```
<?php
$db = mssql_connect("dbsrv02", "requsr", "");
mssql_select_db("ticketDb",$db);
$result = mssql_query("SELECT ticketId, StageOne, StageTwo, StageThree",$db);
$num = mssql_num_rows($result);
$regPlate = $_GET['ticketId'];
$i = 1;

// creating table header
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> 
    <td> num </td> 
    <td> stage1 </td> 
    <td> stage2 </td> 
    <td> stage3 </td> 
    <td> stage </td> 
    </tr>";

while ($myrow = mssql_fetch_array($result))  {
    if ($myrow["StageOne"] = "Completed" and $myrow["StageTwo"] = "Uncomplete" and $myrow["StageThree"] = "Uncomplete" {
       $stage = "StageOne"
    }
    // fecthing row
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> " . $num . "</td>";
    echo "<td> " . $myrow["StageOne"]  . "</td>";
    echo "<td> " . $myrow["StageTwo"]  . "</td>";
    echo "<td> " . $myrow["StageThree"]  . "</td>";
    echo "<td> " . $stage   . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
$i++;
} 
// table tag closing
echo "</table>";

if ($num < 1){ // if there nothing
echo "Sorry, nothing there to see!";
}else{
echo "There are " . $num "s data";
}
?>
```

Comment: I've copied that in, and I am pressing the button but nothing is happening... I feel like I am missing the obvious as I know quite a bit of HTML!

Comment: try to change your button into <input name="find" type="submit"

Comment: The URL changed to http://10.1.172.3/aspdatabase/noprob.php?numberPlate=27391&find=Submit and the body was blank with no page source...

Comment: try to open your php my admin and fill with your sql code
"SELECT ticketId, StageOne, StageTwo, StageThree"

Comment: Don't use phpmyadmin, its MSSQL

Comment: MSSQL is diffrenent with sql like calling table [dbo].[tableName]